# Trouble with script-generated dynamic html element

Tags: javascript, html

I developing comment section for my HTMl page. I place it in `div` container in `body` section in my page, like that:

```
<body>
    ...    
    <div id='commentsTree'></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Commment section generated by script, here it is

```
function createCommentsTree(commentsData) {

    resultHTML = "";

    let commentsArray = JSON.parse(commentsData);
    //let result = "";
    resultHTML = resultHTML + "<ul id='myUL'>"; 

    commentsArray.forEach(element => {

        if (element.hasOwnProperty("subordinates")){
            resultHTML = resultHTML + "<li>" +
                                "<span class='caret'></span><textarea class='textFieldRoot'>" + element.content + "</textarea>" +
                                "<div align='right'>" +
                                "<button>Save</button>" +
                                "<button>Answer</button>" +
                                "<button>Delete</button>" +
                                "</div>";

            createCommentsTreeHyerarchycally(element);

            resultHTML = resultHTML + "</li>";
        }
        else{
            resultHTML = resultHTML + "<li>" +
                                "<textarea class='textField'>" + element.content + "</textarea>" +
                                "<div align='right'>" +
                                "<button>Save</button>" +
                                "<button>Answer</button>" +
                                "<button>Delete</button>" +
                                "</div>" +
                                "</li>";
        }


    });

    resultHTML = resultHTML + "</ul>";

    return resultHTML;

}

function createCommentsTreeHyerarchycally(source) {

    resultHTML = resultHTML + "<ul class='nested'>";

    source.subordinates.forEach(element => {

        if (element.hasOwnProperty("subordinates")){
            resultHTML = resultHTML + "<li>" +
                                "<span class='caret'></span><textarea class='textFieldRoot'>" + element.content + "</textarea>" +
                                "<div align='right'>" +
                                "<button>Save</button>" +
                                "<button>Answer</button>" +
                                "<button>Delete</button>" +
                                "</div>";

            createCommentsTreeHyerarchycally(element);

            resultHTML = resultHTML + "</li>";
        }
        else{
            resultHTML = resultHTML + "<li>" +
                                "<textarea class='textField'>" + element.content + "</textarea>" +
                                "<div align='right'>" +
                                "<button>Save</button>" +
                                "<button>Answer</button>" +
                                "<button>Delete</button>" +
                                "</div>" +
                                "</li>";
        }    

    })

    resultHTML = resultHTML + "</ul>";

}
```

in result i have hyerarchycally comments tree, you can see it on example here

https://jsfiddle.net/Obliterator/wogurs6L/, or, on picture "comment section" added below.[image: comment section and trouble]

On picture you can see "caret" symbol, looks like black small arrow near `textareas`, i mark it on picture. When i click it, comment line must unfold, and show subordinate comment lines. You can try it in example here https://jsfiddle.net/Obliterator/wogurs6L/, in this example it works totally correct. But, in my web page, when i click on "caret" symbol, nohing happens, comment line do not unfold. And this is a problem.

For unfold by clicking "caret" symbol i make this script and css:

script:

```
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
                toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
                this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
                });
            }
```

css:

```
/* Remove default bullets */
    ul, #myUL {
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      .textFieldRoot {
        position: relative;
        left: 15px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .textField {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
      }

      /* Remove margins and padding from the parent ul */
      #myUL {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      /* Style the caret/arrow */
      .caret {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none; /* Prevent text selection */
        position: absolute;
      }

      /* Create the caret/arrow with a unicode, and style it */
      .caret::before {
        content: "\25B6";
        color: black;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 6px;
        vertical-align: top;
      }

      /* Rotate the caret/arrow icon when clicked on (using JavaScript) */
      .caret-down::before {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }

      /* Hide the nested list */
      .nested {
        display: none;
      }

      /* Show the nested list when the user clicks on the caret/arrow (with JavaScript) */
      .active {
        display: block;
      }
```

i add css and script in my page, for which i trying add comment section, that way (treeListScript.js and treeListStyle.css):

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/testapp/lib/others/treeList/treeListScript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/testapp/lib/others/treeList/treeListStyle.css">
...
</head>

<body>
...    
<div id='commentsTree'></div>
...
</body>
```

i create my web page this way:

```
var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm");
                    windowTask.onload = function(){
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("formTitle").innerText = "Task " + selectedRow.taskID;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("taskID").value = selectedRow.taskID;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("title").value = selectedRow.title;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("status").value = selectedRow.status;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("creator").value = selectedRow.creator;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("responsible").value = selectedRow.responsible;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("description").value = selectedRow.description;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("dateCreation").value = selectedRow.dateCreation;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("dateStart").value = selectedRow.dateStart;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("dateFinish").value = selectedRow.dateFinish;
                        var comments = getCommentsTree(selectedRow.taskID, 'task');
                        windowTask.document.getElementById('commentsTree').innerHTML = createCommentsTree(comments);
```

line `windowTask.document.getElementById('commentsTree').innerHTML = createCommentsTree(comments);` creates comment section.

So, what i am doing wrong, what i mus do for my unfold fucntional works correct on my web page? If something unclear, ask, i try explain.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: What is `windowTask`?

Comment: windowTask is HTML-page, where to i trying add my comment section. I create it like that: "var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm");"

Comment: i change question description, maby now it will be more clearelly, i hope.

Comment: Your code that tries to add the click event handler for the `.caret` elements, _when_ does that execute?

Comment: i dont know, this is my question was about, i added it as a script in head section of my web page, for which i trying add comment section, i write about it above. Not whole page generates by script, only comment section.

Comment: i try add my event listener when i create html-page from script, in `onload` event, it's not help.

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem by myself. Reason is i just incorrect add event handler to the `.caret`elements, i add it as script in head section, but i need to add it after i generate comment section, this way:

```
//creating new HTML page +++    
var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm");
windowTask.onload = function(){
windowTask.document.getElementById("formTitle").innerText = "Task " + selectedRow.taskID;
windowTask.document.getElementById("taskID").value = selectedRow.taskID;
windowTask.document.getElementById("title").value = selectedRow.title;
windowTask.document.getElementById("status").value = selectedRow.status;
windowTask.document.getElementById("creator").value = selectedRow.creator;
windowTask.document.getElementById("responsible").value = selectedRow.responsible;
windowTask.document.getElementById("description").value = selectedRow.description;
windowTask.document.getElementById("dateCreation").value = selectedRow.dateCreation;
windowTask.document.getElementById("dateStart").value = selectedRow.dateStart;
windowTask.document.getElementById("dateFinish").value = selectedRow.dateFinish;
//creating new HTML page ---

//creating comment section +++
var comments = getCommentsTree(selectedRow.taskID, 'task');
windowTask.document.getElementById('commentsTree').innerHTML = createCommentsTree(comments);
//creating comment section ---

//adding event handler +++
var toggler = windowTask.document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
 toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
  this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
                         });
                      }
//adding event handler ---
```

now everything works fine. If anyone spend some time for my question, thx.